# pandoc and rmarkdown: Can't fetch an image one level above a rmarkdown document

Tags: r, knitr, pandoc, r-markdown

I am just starting to use rmarkdown, pandoc and knitr. I am having a great deal of difficult trying to get pandoc to fetch an image that is one level above an  rmarkdown document. For example, consider our project directory is ~/test, the following rmarkdown is located at ~/test/scripts:

````
---
title: "test"
---

```{r global_options, include=FALSE}
library('knitr')
opts_knit$set(root.dir = '~/test')
```

![test](figures/test.svg)
````

I then run the command `Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('scripts/test.Rmd')"` from the ~/test directory. And it gives me the error:

```
pandoc: Could not fetch figures/test.svg
figures/test.svg: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

I would have thought by setting the root.dir to be the project directory, that pandoc will fetch files relative to that? But it seems that the "working directory" is always set to relative to the where the rmarkdown document is? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks,

```
>sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_CA.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_CA.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_CA.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_CA.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_CA.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_CA.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_CA.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] vimcom_1.0-0   setwidth_1.0-3 colorout_1.0-2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.1.0`
```

Comment: Does it work if you run the script from inside `scripts` directory?

Comment: Unfortunately no. When I ran, cd ~/test/scripts && Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('scripts/test.Rmd')" I get the same error.

Comment: I think you should change 'scripts/test.Rmd' to 'test.Rmd' when you run it from inside `scripts`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pandoc does not know **knitr**'s `root.dir` option. You have to write paths relative to the current working directory, e.g., `../figures/test.svg`. Or run `Rscript` under the `scripts` directory.

If you just started using **rmarkdown** and **knitr**, I strongly recommend you not to use the `root.dir` option, unless you really understand what it means. These directories can be [really, really tricky](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/913).

Comment: This is what confuses me. When I run Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('scripts/test.Rmd') from the ~/test directory. Isn't my working directory ~/test since that is where I called it from? And figures is a folder (forgot to mention this) that is at the same level as ~/test. So this means the path figures/test.svg should correct then, yet it doesn't work?

Comment: @user2774754 Your working directory in R is `~/test`. But because you `render('scripts/test.Rmd')`, I believe rmarkdown will temporarily change the working directory to `scripts/`. In that case, you will have to use `../figures/test.svg`. Personally I recommend users to compile an Rmd file in its directory, and think all paths relative to the directory of the Rmd file. If you render an Rmd file from another directory, things can get very tricky.

Comment: ok that makes sense. The reason why I prefer to run Rscript one directory above the Rmd is because in practice I actually have a "wrapper" script that calls the Rmd file. The wrapper script is a R file that is responsible for loading all the input data and pre-processing data. And then it is the script that the rmarkdown::render() function. So when it loads all the data, the data is with respect to where I call it (which is what should happen). In practice, do you load and process all data in your Rmd file too? I would like to know so I know what the proper practice is...

Comment: @user2774754 I do not do this very often. When I do, I put data files under the same directory of the Rmd file. I understand that thinking of these different directories is a pain in practice...

Comment: @Yuhui Ok that's good to know. That's unfortunate that the directory handling is so complicated! What I've got going is a generic patient report .Rmd file that uses patient specific data loaded in from a wrapper script and calls the Rmd file to generate a patient report. I suppose that the Rmd files could set at the parent directory, and all the input data is relative to the Rmd from there. Just makes things a bit messy when I have many different Rmd (not to mention child Rmd files)...