# Pandoc: error 1, binary file does not exist

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc

I'm having problems knitting an .rmd file to a .html (and pdf for that matter) file using rmarkdown. The report that I'm trying to knit in the following example is just the example report you get when starting a new rmakrdown document.

This is the error message I get:

```
==> rmarkdown::render('C:/Users/***/Documents/test/test.Rmd',  encoding = 'UTF-8');


processing file: test.Rmd
  |..........                                                            |  14%
  ordinary text without R code

  |....................                                                  |  29%
label: setup (with options) 
List of 1
 $ include: logi FALSE

  |..............................                                        |  43%
  ordinary text without R code

  |........................................                              |  57%
label: cars
  |..................................................                    |  71%
  ordinary text without R code

  |............................................................          |  86%
label: pressure (with options) 
List of 1
 $ echo: logi FALSE

  |......................................................................| 100%
  ordinary text without R code


output file: test.knit.md

"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS test.utf8.md --to html4 --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output test.html --email-obfuscation none --self-contained --standalone --section-divs --template "\\storage-***.se\home$\****\My Documents\R\win-library\4.0\rmarkdown\rmd\h\default.html" --no-highlight --variable highlightjs=1 --variable "theme:bootstrap" --include-in-header "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpc1mrLs\rmarkdown-str511010115ff7.html" --mathjax --variable "mathjax-url:https://mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML" --lua-filter "\\storage-****.se/home$/****/My Documents/R/win-library/4.0/rmarkdown/rmd/lua/pagebreak.lua" --lua-filter "\\storage-***-se/home$/*****/My Documents/R/win-library/4.0/rmarkdown/rmd/lua/latex-div.lua" 
pandoc.exe: \\: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 1
Execution halted
```

Pandoc tries to reach a file saved on my computer but for some reason can't find it. This is my work computer where everything is saved locally and then uploaded to a server. I have talked with IT at my office and they don't know why it wont work.
I have managed to get a rmarkdown report before when I moved EVERYTHING (r project, packages and the files where I do my analysis) to a map that is not uploaded to the backup server.
However, this is not a safe way since there is no backup, obviously. I've tried to just have the r-project locally for the knitting but it doesn't work either.
Why can't pandoc find this binary file and is there a way I can get it to work without having to risk the safety of my work? If not, is there another way of creating similar files without pandoc?

I have seen similar questions but nothing that could give me any answers. Or give the people at the IT department any clues.

Thanks!
Johanna

Here is the session information:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17134)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Swedish_Sweden.1252  LC_CTYPE=Swedish_Sweden.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Swedish_Sweden.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=Swedish_Sweden.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_4.0.2  htmltools_0.5.0 tools_4.0.2     yaml_2.2.1      rmarkdown_2.3  
 [6] knitr_1.29      xfun_0.16       digest_0.6.25   rlang_0.4.7     evaluate_0.14
```

Versions:

```
> version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          4                           
minor          0.2                         
year           2020                        
month          06                          
day            22                          
svn rev        78730                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
nickname       Taking Off Again 

> pandoc_version()
[1] ‘2.7.2’

> pandoc_available()
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the problem!

The actual problem was the path of the `rmarkdown` package. It was on my `//storage`... path. What I finally had to do was to go into system settings and add an environmental variable for `R_LIBS_USER` to my `H:/` path. Now when `pandoc` is looking for the `rmarkdown` details it can find the path.

Comment: Johanna, could you explain this in more detail? I have the same problem. Where are system settings and how to add this variable? Tnx

Comment: Hi, I have a windows computer so I followed this procedure https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/
But instead of altering the path in the system variables, I focused on the top window "used variables" and pressed "add" and entered the name of the r variable and then the correct path. I could find which variables to change by looking at sys.env() in R and selecting those variables with the wrong path. For me it was anything with \\ in it.
I hope this helps!

Comment: At the end for me, everything worked when I just opened a new R project and did all over again. Strange. But tnx.

Answer (score 0):

Using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27910312/pandoc-and-rmarkdown-cant-fetch-an-image-one-level-above-a-rmarkdown-document) as research. try using the RELATIVE path for your file. in this one you are using the absolute path *C:/Users/...* and this temporarily changes R's working directory.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In the link you sent me I understood that the problem is for pandoc to find a picture that was going in to the report. As for me there is nothing for pandoc to retrieve since the report I'm asking it to knit is empty. 
I see that I can ask for the knit function to use different "knit directory"s. But I none of those work either. 
Or do you mean that I should give an relative path for r studio to reach pandoc. How do I do that?

Comment: A further comment:
I understand it as rmarkdown::render() cant find pandoc.exe
However:
> pandoc_available()
[1] TRUE

so rstudio can reach pandoc.

Comment: Can you create a simplified version of your .Rmd file? I think pandoc is just looking in the wrong place to render the document. You said this is all local. Are referencing any other files inside your .Rmd file?

Comment: The .Rmd file is empty of information, there is only a bit of text. However, it is placed in my working directory which is not in a C:/ path, while pandoc is installed through rstudio on c:/programs. So I believe it is as you said before, I need to use relative paths. However, I don't know where to implement that. right now the command for knit is: rmarkdown::render('//storage-*****.se/home$/*****/My Documents/test2/test2.Rmd',  encoding = 'UTF-8', knit_root_dir = '~/');
Is there something here I should change?

Comment: What if you went into Rstudio and typed `setwd(//storage-*****.se/home$/*****/My Documents/test2/)` to set the working directory to where the file is. And then did `rmarkdown::render(test2.Rmd)` leave out the other arguments (encoding = 'UTF-8', knit_root_dir = '~/')) just to see what we get

Comment: I get the same error :pandoc.exe: \\: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 1

Comment: You said in your question that you were able to get it to work with a previous set up. Why can't you use your previous set up and then create a shortcut folder on your desktop mapped to the network drive so you can knit and render documents, and then just same them to the shortcut folder? I am not sure why this error is giving you such a hard time. apologize I couldn't help more

Comment: Ohh smart idea! I'm going to give it a try.
I don't know either. I've tried to find similar errors in forums but their solutions never work for me. I guess it's something with the folder system at my workplace. I'm thankful for your time anyways!

Comment: I think I get it now!!  In the error message pandoc.exe cant find '//'. I believe that that is from '//storage-*****.se/home$/*****/My Documents'. I need to find a way to change '//storage-*****.se/home$/***** to H:/. Even thogh i render with H:/ it still calls the // path for the template and lua filter. I have changed it to H:/ working directory in my global options but I need to dig deeper into like system environmental variables.