# Using relative paths in Rmarkdown when knitting from two different locations

Tags: r-markdown, pandoc, figure

My problem is with use of relative links and "compiling" (knitting).

I'm writing a book using RMarkdown. Since the file will be relatively large, I need to split into subfiles and directories.

I have a masterfile which only includes links to chapters(chap1, chap2, ...). There is a file for each chapter and each needs references to some figures (fig1,...).

I would like to be able to knit masterfile.Rmd and chap1.Rmd independently from each others so to get one file for chapters, and one file for the whole book.

Here is how my files are organized (MVE). Directories are displayed in upper case.

- ROOT

  - masterfile.Rmd
  - FIGURES

    - fig1.pdf
    - fig2.pdf
  - CHAPTERS

    - chap1.Rmd
    - chap2.Rmd
    - ...

The code of masterfile.Rmd is as follows:

```
{r child = '/chapters/chap1.Rmd'}
```

The code of chap1.Rmd is as follows:

```
![](../figures/fig1.pdf)
```

As I knit from `chap1.Rmd`, everything is fine. As I knit from `masterfile`, I get the following message:

*[WARNING] Could not fetch resource '../figures/fig1.pdf': PandocResourceNotFound "../figures/fig1.pdf"*

It seems that `fig1.pdf` cannot be found. I guess that this is because the include statement in master file only "copies" the code of `chap1.Rmd` and "executes" it in the `ROOT` directory (not in the `CHAPTERS` directory) so ".." drives to location that does not exist (before ROOT) when knitted from `masterfile`.

I could change the setting and write `![](/figures/fig1.pdf)` in `chap1.Rmd` file. It would work fine when knitting from `masterfile` but no longer from `chap1.Rmd`.

Do you know how to have both?

Comment: I would recommend you to have a look at the `here`-package

Comment: not sure how RStudio and r-markdown invoke pandoc... but in plain pandoc, all paths are usually relative to your current working directory, but you can use the [--resource-path option](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--resource-path) to search more paths.

Comment: Thanks Florian and mb21. I'll try both options. I let you know. Thanks

Comment: [used this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27910312/pandoc-and-rmarkdown-cant-fetch-an-image-one-level-above-a-rmarkdown-document) and the link Yihui Xie posted and the following comments. I think you are on to something regarding the `ROOT` directory and moving around to other directories while knitting. Wonder if having the chapters in the same directory as the at the `masterfile` with only the figures in their own directory would allow you to knit both successfully. update us on what you find out

Comment: @Florian I had a look at the here package (good to know that package !). However, it does not provide a solution since "here" will depend on file location.

Comment: @mb21  I added "pandoc_args: ["--resource-path=.:chapitres", "--self-contained", "--extract-media=.:chapitres"]" in the yaml settings. I started with resource-path only. I did not work. Then I added selfcontained and extract-media in case this would help. However, it does not work either :(

Comment: @DanielJachetta Yes, this is my exact problem ! I tried the ROOT.dir options but as in the example, it does not work here. I think I'll have to put all Rmd files into a single dir as you suggest. I wanted to avoid this because of many rmd files (+ PDF, + DOC + ancillary files) in the root dir, but I understand it is complicated to do otherwise (I am a true beginner in MD and do not want to introduce things I do not really understand/master). Thanks all for all your suggestions !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the RMarkdown community!

Due to KnitR, Rmd, and pandoc inter-workings, this is not as easy of a solution as you'd think, but a directory restructure would almost be easier.

Even if you look at Rmarkdown author's newest book `RMarkdown Cookbook`[HERE](https://github.com/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook). They have all the chapters in the `ROOT` directory, and only sub directories for images(and possibly figures).

resources:

[1. Other SO similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27910312/pandoc-and-rmarkdown-cant-fetch-an-image-one-level-above-a-rmarkdown-document)

[2. Github options knitr question](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/913)

[3. similar question from Rstudio community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/pandoc-document-conversion-failed-with-error-99/18035/3)

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Yes, you're totally right: if experienced dev use this approach, it's probably the most reasonable one for a beginner like me. The setwd('papers') instruction (2nd link) seems interesting. However, I'm not comfortable with all side effects (change of output directory ?). I prefer stick to someting I "master".  Thanks for the link to the book. Very helpful to re-organize the file tree !

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the [Lua filter](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/docs/articles/lua-filters.html#lua-filter) feature to rewrite image paths when knitting the main file. E.g.

```lua
function Image (img)
  img.src = img.src:gsub('^%.%./', './')
  return img
end
```

This will replace a path like `../figures/fig1.pdf` with `./figures/fig1.pdf`.

Use the code writing it to a file and calling adding it via `pandoc_args` (in the main file only).

```yaml
---
output:
  html_document:
    pandoc_args: ["--lua-filter=filter.lua"]
---
```

Comment: Hello Tarleb,
Thanks. I've never used functions in Markdown.
Does it mean that
a) I create a new file in the "master-file" and "chapter" directories and put the definition of the version in a file called "filter.lua"
b) I add the pandoc argument
c) When and where should I call the Image function ? Does it mean that when I call an image from a chapter file, I should write something like

\includegraphics{Image(myimage.pdf)} ?

Sorry if this is a very naive question !

Thanks,

best

Eric

Comment: The way Lua filters work is by modifying pandoc's internal document representation. The above changes all images whose path starts with `../`. This only makes sense when compiling the master file. Therefore: 1) write the function to a file called `filter.lua` in your project's ROOT; 2) add the `pandoc_args` snippet to your metadata in main.Rmd; 3) enjoy. No need to modify your other docs.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I'm sorry I need to do something else and cannot try right now. I'll try it by the end of the week and let you know. Thanks again

Comment: Hello Tarleb. Deeply sorry to say that is does not work :( I did exactly what you described. Could it depend on the method I use to call an image ? I use the function as described in the question. Maybe there is another function (HTML ?) that will "recognize" image as it and to what the function should do?

Comment: Tested it again, works fine. Can you post a minimal example somewhere, ideally as a zip?

Comment: Hello Tarleb. Sorry for the very late reply. I eventually bypassed the problem by organizing files differently. Thanks again for your support.